# Storing multiple checkbutton strings into different variables with python tkinter

Tags: checkbox, tkinter, python-3.3, subdirectory, storing-information

I'm making a python program using tkinter that will create a folder name based on a string and also create subfolders based on what check box is selected.

i.e. if the "banana" checkbox is selected it will create a banana folder inside that string named folder. This is what I need this to do:

1. A list of check boxes that the user will check off (these will create subfolders) **THIS IS THE PART I'M HAVING TROUBLE WITH**
2. Browse a directory (this is the path where the parent folder will be created)
3. Name a folder (enter in a string and create a folder where all the subfolders will go under)

Here's my code so far. I know there's probably a better way to store all the checked boxes but I don't know how to do that yet:

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import *
from tkinter.filedialog import askdirectory
import os, sys

def browse():
    dir = askdirectory()
    if dir:
        path.set(dir)

def genAsset():
    assetPath=path.get()
    assetName=asset.get()
    expFold=export.get()
    bakFold=bake.get()
    sceFold=scene.get()
    texFold=texture.get()
    scuFold=sculpt.get()
    refFold=reference.get()
    renFold=render.get()
    engFold=engine.get()
    os.makedirs(assetPath+"/"+assetName+"/")
    os.makedirs(assetPath+"/"+assetName+"/"+expFold+"/")
    os.makedirs(assetPath+"/"+assetName+"/"+bakFold+"/")
    os.makedirs(assetPath+"/"+assetName+"/"+sceFold+"/")
    os.makedirs(assetPath+"/"+assetName+"/"+texFold+"/")
    os.makedirs(assetPath+"/"+assetName+"/"+scuFold+"/")
    os.makedirs(assetPath+"/"+assetName+"/"+refFold+"/")
    os.makedirs(assetPath+"/"+assetName+"/"+renFold+"/")
    os.makedirs(assetPath+"/"+assetName+"/"+engFold+"/")

#create the window and title 
window=Tk()
window.title("v1.0")

#define variables and images
path=StringVar()
asset=StringVar()
VMR=PhotoImage(file="VMR.gif")
selectFolders=StringVar()

export=StringVar()
bake=StringVar()
scene=StringVar()
texture=StringVar()
sculpt=StringVar()
reference=StringVar()
render=StringVar()
engine=StringVar()


#define checkbuttons of folders to generate and store textvaiable

expButt=Checkbutton(window, text="export", textvariable=export).pack()
bakButt=Checkbutton(window, text="bake").pack()
sceButt=Checkbutton(window, text="scene").pack()
texButt=Checkbutton(window, text="texture").pack()
scuButt=Checkbutton(window, text="sculpt").pack()
refButt=Checkbutton(window, text="reference").pack()
renButt=Checkbutton(window, text="renders").pack()
engButt=Checkbutton(window, text="engine").pack()

#display the image file
hdrImg=Label(window, image=VMR)
hdrImg.photo=VMR

#select path and define asset name, store strings
lDirec=Label(window, text="Folder Directory:").pack()
ePath=Entry(window, textvariable=path, width=50).pack()
bBrowse=Button(window, text="Browse Path", command=browse).pack()
lAsset=Label(window, text="Asset Name:").pack()
eAsset=Entry(window, textvariable=asset, width=50).pack()
bCreate=Button(window, text="Create Asset", command=genAsset).pack()

window.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 1):

You can create two lists: one for the names of the subdirectories, and another one for storing `IntVar`s to track if each `Checkbutton` is checked or not. Thus, you can zip both lists in your `genAsset` function, and then create the subdirectory if the value of the corresponding `IntVar` is not zero.

This way you can also reduce a lot of code duplication in the callback function and simplify the creation of the widgets.

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter.filedialog import askdirectory
import os, sys

window = tk.Tk()

def browse():
    directory = askdirectory()
    if directory:
        path.set(directory)

def genAsset():
    asset_path = path.get()
    asset_name = asset.get()
    for var, folder in zip(variables, folders):
        folder_path = os.path.join(asset_path, asset_name, folder)
        if var.get() and not os.path.exists(folder_path):
            os.makedirs(folder_path)

path = tk.StringVar()
asset = tk.StringVar()

folders = ["export", "bake", "scene", "texture", "sculpt", "reference", "renders", "engine"]
variables = []
for folder in folders:
    var = tk.IntVar()
    tk.Checkbutton(window, text=folder, variable=var).pack()
    variables.append(var)

dir_label = tk.Label(window, text="Folder Directory:")
path_entry = tk.Entry(window, textvariable=path, width=50)
browse_button = tk.Button(window, text="Browse Path", command=browse)
asset_label = tk.Label(window, text="Asset Name:")
asset_entry = tk.Entry(window, textvariable=asset, width=50)
create_button = tk.Button(window, text="Create Asset", command=genAsset)

dir_label.pack()
path_entry.pack()
browse_button.pack()
asset_label.pack()
asset_entry.pack()
create_button.pack()

window.mainloop()
```

*PS: Keep in mind that `pack()` returns `None`, so you shouldn't store the result of calling this function but create the widget first and then call `pack()`.*